# Bitrix 1c. Вывести список пользователей и детальную страницу о пользователе

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу найти как вывести детальную страницу о пользователе. Создал раздел со списком пользователей в ручную, не используя компоненты. Дальше пытаюсь перейти на страницу пользователя с указанием его ID, но так как физически страницы не существует я прописал в urlrewrite условие к какому файлу обращаться. Но к сожалению это не сработало. Может у кого то есть информация как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код страницы со списком пользователей, условие urlrewrite и содержимое страницы, на которую ведет это условие. Сейчас невозможно сказать, что не так

Comment: Я в итоге воспользовался компонентов из маркета Список пользователей и Детальный пользователь, так как было ограничение по времени выполнения(